# How to open an Excel file in PHP?

Tags: php, import-from-excel

How can an excel file be opened, all cols/rows read in an array etc the same way .csv files can be? Is there any built in libraries/classes for that in php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've use the [PHP Excel Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader)

and here is a [Good Write-up From Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3336-Reading-and-Writing-Spreadsheets-with-PHP)